RTMP server for Android
I want to receive RTMP stream on Andoroid Phone from GoPro. I would like to install some kind of RTMP server on Android device which would forward the stream to the mobile application on the same device. Do you know any way to handle this issue from mobile application? I have seen the possibility of installing docker container on the phone, but I would rather do it from java/kotlin application, without root privileges.
Principle of working:
Client(GoPro) -> RTMP Server (the part I need to host on a smartphone) -> Client (Android Application)
The RTMP server in the middle is probably essential because GoPro demands a connection to the RTMP server to start the stream. I have managed to enable the server in the hotspot network on the PC, but the goal is to host it on the smartphone.
I have made a research on the internet and I found such a methode - but it is old repository and I could not confirm it is working.
https://github.com/tatowilson/Cross-Compile-Nginx-with-RTMP-Module-for-Android
Docker container is another option but I would like to omit rooting the phone.

There are some ready-to-play solutions. For example, you can find a very simple client here. This approach is based on this SDK. Video tutorial.

Thank you anil for your answer however, that is not what I meant. I edited the post -  a schema what precisely I need was added. I need to host on smartphone an instance of RTMP server which would collect stream from GoPro (same server has to generate address to stream) and then to convey this stream from a server to smartphone application. Or something that imitates behaviour of such a server - including handshakes and maintaining session
